# Formatting issue with HTML2PDF

Tags: python, html2pdf

I am using HTML2PDF for converting my html file with css code in it. I am not getting proper output. I tried every thing so far but I don't have any idea what is going on in my code. Can any tell me what am I doing wrong here.

**This is my HTML file (my.html) *****

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>PDF Template</title>

<style type="text/css">

body {font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;line-height:20px;color:#444444;text-align:left;margin:0;padding:40px 0;}


#wrapper {height:auto; width:660px; overflow:hidden; margin:0 auto; background-color:#E0DAE9; 
padding:15px; border:5px solid #EFECF4;}

#content {height:auto; width:620px; overflow:hidden; margin:0 auto; background-color:#FFFFFF; padding:20px;}


.left {height:auto; width:300px; overflow:hidden; float:left; margin:0 20px 0 0;}

.right {height:auto; width:300px; overflow:hidden; float:right;}

#center {height:auto; width:620px; overflow:hidden;}


</style>
</head>
<body>  
  <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="content">

    <h1>$Lopram seu chacege amtoe smgho</h1>
    <div class="left">
       <h2>Recipient:</h2>
       <p>John Doe</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
            <h2>Expires On:</h2>
        <p>May 20, 2012</p>
    </div>  
    <h2>Fine Print:</h2>
    <p>Lorem poeoh ochoe. Toroam ozohm. Vsoram soeaose.</p>
    <div id="center">
        <div class="left">      
        <h2>Address:</strong></h2>
        <ul>
            <li>950 XX St.</li>

        </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

   </div>   
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is the python code:**

```
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
import cStringIO as StringIO

def CreatePDF():

    ## Let's create a file name for pdf
    file_name = "mytest.pdf"

    # Create a file object
    pdf_file = open(file_name, "wb")

    # Open pdf file
    html_file = open("my.html", 'rb')  # I also tried with open("my.html")

    # Create pdf using pisa
    pdf = pisa.CreatePDF( html_file.read(), pdf_file)

    html_file.close()
    pdf_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

html2pdf doesn't support float in css, if you want to do the layout, try "table" instead.